# Should we rollback release if integration tests fail?

Tags: devops, continuous-deployment, trunk

We are using trunk-based development, and I am confused wheater we should rollback our deployment if integration tests fail? P.S we are using microservices and if A microservice wants to interact with B microservice or any third party service, which is down for some reason should we revert back our deployment?

Comment: A failure of an _integration_ test might mean that some other microservice is failing.  The bigger question is whether all the _unit_ tests for a given microservice are passing.  So...are the unit tests all passing?

Comment: yes, unit tests are passing.

Comment: Then you could argue that a microservice all of whose unit tests are passing is fit for deployment.

Comment: That's my case here just want to improve my CI/CD flow.